# Android assets - FileNotFound

Tags: android, xml, android-assets

I am inside a fragment in this class:

```
public class NetworksList extends Fragment{
```

Also inside my `onCreate` function I'have this piece of code:

```
        XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
        try {
            pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();

            InputStream in_s = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("temp.xml");
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(in_s, null);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "size: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            parseXML(parser);

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Wish I am trying to use to open XML Files. I have my XML file in the assets folder, but I am getting:

```
05-08 18:03:11.034  24645-24645/pt.smartgeo.aees W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: temp.xml
05-08 18:03:11.034  24645-24645/pt.smartgeo.aees W/System.err﹕ at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
05-08 18:03:11.034  24645-24645/pt.smartgeo.aees W/System.err﹕ at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:316)
05-08 18:03:11.034  24645-24645/pt.smartgeo.aees W/System.err﹕ at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:290)
05-08 18:03:11.034  24645-24645/pt.smartgeo.aees W/System.err﹕ at pt.smartgeo.aees.NetworksList$2.onClick(NetworksList.java:77)
```

FileNotFound... How can I know where to put my temp.xml file so I can open it in my NetworksList Class?

Comment: That looks like it should work. You can put your xml in the `raw` folder and access it via it's id: `context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.temp);`

Comment: where's the raw folder?

Comment: You can create it under the `res` folder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you are sure to have a file `temp.xml` inside `/assets` folder, (must be at the same level of `/src` and `/res` inside your project), just try a refresh, <kbd>F5</kbd>.

the way that you are loading the file from `assets` is correct:

```
 InputStream is = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("temp.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
InputStream in_s = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("temp");
```

I mean eliminate the ".xml" part. I tried this for the same error and it worked for me!